# ColdFusion dateformat wrong format

Tags: date, coldfusion, dateformatter

I have an input text where I get the date:

```
<input type="text" name="myDate" />
```

After submitting the form, I save this date into the database doing a dateformat:

```
#DateFormat(myDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")#
```

If the user enters: 02/19/1948, it saves correct: 1948-02-19.
But if the user enters: 02191948, it saves: 7901-05-07. Why? Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Usually date inputs are more strict than a single text box.  Drop downs for month, day, year are pretty standard and you wouldn't have to deal with issues like this.

Comment: I see... I have a tcal javascript calendar plugin, but it allows me to enter date like 02191948

Comment: Do you know if I can do a JS validation before submitting the form?

Comment: Date format returns a string.  It's the wrong approach.  You want to cast the input to a date object instead, and use query parameters.  Then there is the matter of validating input prior to using it.  The actual validation depends on your business rules.

Comment: Please, please, please don't store a date in your database as a string. If you absolutely need to, send it as yyyymmdd, and your database _should_ be able to interpret that how it needs. Be sure to watch out for the differences between DateFormat() and DateTimeFormat() and how they interpret YYYY and yyyy. Masks will bite you at the end of December. Fair warning.

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion's `DateFormat()` expects a valid date representation. ColdFusion is very sloppy when it comes to what type of input is considered valid. Safe date inputs are [ODBC literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences) and [most of ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Beware of format pitfalls like `mm/dd` and `dd.mm` and avoid them altogether, if possible.

What you want to use is [LSParseDateTime()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsparsedatetime.html). It allows you to specify the locale and format you expect and make ColdFusion parse a date object based on the input.  It's not fail-safe though, meaning you have to `try-catch` it in case the input doesn't match at all. There is a fail-safe [LSIsDate()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-l/lsisdate.html), which tells you if the input is considered valid in the specified locale. But either way, it's a game of format detection. Having fixed `<select>` tags for month, day and year is the easiest way to avoid issues.

Loose demo for localized date input:

```
<cfset myLocale = "en_US">
<cfset myDateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd">

<cfset dateByInput = "">
<cfset errorReason = "">

<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "myDate")>
    <cfif lsIsDate(FORM["myDate"], myLocale)>
        <cftry>
            <cfset dateByInput = lsParseDateTime(FORM["myDate"], myLocale, myDateFormat)>
            <cfcatch>
                <cfset errorReason = ("Your input is invalid. Please enter in the following format: " & myDateFormat)>
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset errorReason = ("Your input is invalid. Please enter in the following format: " & myDateFormat)>
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<cfset dateByInputIsValid = isDate(dateByInput)> <!--- note: it's sufficient to use the unlocalized date check here, since dateByInput is either not valid at all or a (universal) date object --->

<cfif dateByInputIsValid>

    <!--- store date input in database --->
    <cftry>
        <cfset myDatasource = "exampleDS">
        <cfquery datasource="#myDatasource#">
            INSERT INTO `myDatabase`.`myTable` ( `myDateColumn` ) VALUES (
                <cfqueryparam value="#dateByInput#" cfSqlType="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP">
            )
        </cfquery>
        <cfcatch>
            <cfset errorReason = "Oh noes, something went wrong attempting to save your input.">
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

</cfif>

<cfoutput>
    <cfif dateByInputIsValid>
        <p>Date input valid: #lsDateFormat(dateByInput, myDateFormat, myLocale)#</p>
        <cfif len(errorReason)>
            <p>#errorReason#</p>
        <cfelse>
            <p>Input successfully stored in database.</p>
        </cfif>
    <cfelse>
        <cfif len(errorReason)>
            <p>#errorReason#</p>
        </cfif>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="myDate" />
            <button type="submit">send</button>
        </form>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```